# Market data and machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I have the following general question regarding the use of ML in quantitative finance:

Lets say I want to train a model (for simplicity lets consider a neural network), so that I feed some market data for a stock, and I want to compute something on it (the specific goal is not important here, imagine just a pricer). What happens is that usually the market data on a stock has a non-fixed structure. For example for stock $A$ I might have $n$ dividends, whereas for stock $B$ I may have $m$. Therefore, feeding dividend data into the model is not a straight-forward task, as the size of the entry values for the model is not constant and the input for a NN has to be an array of fixed size. I used the dividends example, but this applies to everything: volatility surface (I might have a $n_1 \times n_2$ matrix for one stock and a $m_1 \times m_2$ sized volatility surface for another), etc.

For rate curves PCA decomposition is well suited, so it might be simple to transform a variable-sized vector of date-value tuples into a fixed $d$-dimensional structure. But what about other inputs? What is the common practice?

I know there are many possibilities in ML, but I would like to know what are the ones that are more readily or well suited to be used in finance. References are also welcome.